# ProGuard doesn't performs obfuscation of Object's methods

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

In purpose of learning how `ProGuard` works I have created tiny `Android` example, added some `jar` to it, wrote couple lines of code, enabled `ProGuard` and so on.

my ProGuard options are next

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
public static int v(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int e(...);
}
-optimizationpasses 5
-optimizations !class/unboxing/enum
```

So after reverse engeneering of my APK names to all `Object`'s methods, such as `toString()`, `hashCode()`, `equals()` remains the same. Apart from `Object`'s methods, names of `Externalizable` methods remains too

So have you any idea why it happens, could it be fixed at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ProGuard cannot obfuscate methods that do not originate in your classes (where "your" includes JAR/AARs that you compile in).

Anything you override from framework-supplied classes needs to stay intact. Otherwise, the framework cannot call those methods, since ProGuard is not obfuscating the firmware-installed framework classes on ~1.5 billion Android devices.

Comment: sounds sad, so in case of my readExternal/writeExternal methods contains some important logic, which "hacker" can easily find because of method names, what can I do in this case?

Comment: @MikeHerasimov: A hacker can find that code anyway. ProGuard obfuscation is of limited use given modern reverse engineering tools.

Comment: I'm apologize for too many questions, sir, but do you know any free tools that can obfuscate code better than ProGuard? (of course if such exists)

Comment: @MikeHerasimov: It is impossible for there to be a tool that addresses your concern from your question. It would not surprise me if there are better obfuscaters than ProGuard, though I have not researched the topic, but they cannot change the fact that the framework classes come from devices, and so their methods are not obfuscated and cannot be obfuscated in subclasses. You're welcome to move your business logic to other methods and call them from the non-obfuscated methods, but that will not be a major problem for those reverse engineering the code.

Comment: seems like It's all I can do for code obfuscation, thank you for you answer and your time, have a nice day mr Mark ;)

Comment: my pal just said that it's rude to call somebody by mr + his FirstName, so sorry about this I didn't know